# Skipping rows in results is not currently supported

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, advantage-database-server

I am using Advantage database server 10 with MVC Entity FW. While trying to skip items of an IQueryable list, getting an error "Skipping rows in results is not currently supported."

```
allItems.Skip(itemIndex).Take(pageSize);
```

Any familiar with this error please help, skip works fine only if results converted using ToList()

Answer (score 1):

Advantage Database Server added support for the SKIP operator in version 11.1.  I wold recommend getting the latest 11.1 as there was a bug found.

The addition was made to the .Net provider (client), but if you update the client you will need to have at least the same version (or higher) of the server.

Here is a link to the "What's New" in the 11.1 help file.
[Advantage 11.1 Help - What's New](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can store all objects in the session and next time load from session.

```
if(Session["allItems"] == Null)
    Session["allItems"] = allItems.Select(x=>x).ToList();
}
allItems = ((List<the object type>)Session["allItems"]).Skip(itemIndex).Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: Yes.You can save it to the session and then load from session if you want to optimize it.

Comment: Sorry, taking all data from db is not a best practice I believe.